# ITMS-90432: "Invalid Swift Support" doesn't have the correct file type for this location

Tags: ios, cmake, ios-frameworks

I have been having a hard time publishing my app on the AppStore. Im using the Application Loader and i keep getting the following error.

> ERROR ITMS-90432: "Invalid Swift Support. The file HelloWorld.app/Frameworks/Fabric.framework doesn’t have the correct file type for this location. Ensure you’re using the correct file, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it."

Now the *ipa* is being packaged manually from the app created from XCode (thats generated using CMake)
This is the structure of the ipa

```
HelloWorld/Payload/HelloWorld.app/
├── AppIcon29x29@2x.png
├── AppIcon29x29@2x~ipad.png
├── AppIcon29x29~ipad.png
├── AppIcon40x40@2x.png
├── AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png
├── AppIcon40x40~ipad.png
├── AppIcon60x60@2x.png
├── AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
├── AppIcon76x76~ipad.png
├── Frameworks
│   └── Fabric.framework
├── HelloWorld
├── Info.plist
├── LaunchImage-700-568h@2x.png
├── LaunchImage-700-Landscape@2x~ipad.png
├── LaunchImage-700-Landscape~ipad.png
├── LaunchImage-700-Portrait@2x~ipad.png
├── LaunchImage-700-Portrait~ipad.png
├── PkgInfo
├── Settings.bundle
│   ├── Root.plist
│   └── en.lproj
│       └── Root.strings
├── _CodeSignature
│   └── CodeResources
├── assets
│   ├── drawable
│   │   └── default
│   │       └── logo.png
│   ├── layout
│   │   └── default
│   │       ├── HelloWorld_MainComp.layout
│   │       └── HelloWorld_MainComp.timeline
│   └── text
└── embedded.mobileprovision
```

I have even tried working with different frameworks (Facebook iOS SDK) getting the same result.
I have tried adding a *Symbols* and *SwiftSupport* (while also copying the frameworks from the Framework directory in the app bundle) folder at the root of the *ipa* including the Payload directory like so.

```
├── Payload
│   └── HelloWorld.app
│       ├── ...
│       └── Frameworks
│           └── Fabric.framework
├── SwiftSupport
│   └── Fabric.framework
└── Symbols
```

Before the application bundle is built (app not ipa) i remove the uneeded architectures from the framework (i386, x86_64) using Apple's *lipo* tool and sign the framework using my distribution certificate.
Also to note, the framework i am using (Fabric) does not contain Swift support as seen by Apple's *otool* (no *libswift*.dylib* in otool output)

```
otool -L Fabric.framework
Archive : Fabric.framework (architecture armv7)
Fabric.framework(FABApplication.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABSettingsOnboardingManager.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABByteUtility.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABUUID.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABIcon.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(Fabric.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABNetworkOperation.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABHost.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABURLBuilder.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABCertificatePinner.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABAppIconUtility.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABMultipartMimeStreamEncoder.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABSettings.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABApplicationIdentiferModel.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABDownloadAndSaveSettingsOperation.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABCerts.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABNetworkResponseHandler.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABOnboardingOperation.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABNetworkClient.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABConstants.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(CLSdSYM.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(CLSCodeMapping.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(CLSMachOBinary.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(CLSMachOSlice.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(CLSMachO.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSessionDownloadTask.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSessionTask.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSessionDataTask.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSession.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSessionConfiguration.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSessionUploadTask.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(CLSUserDefaults.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABAsyncOperation.o) (architecture armv7):
Fabric.framework(FABCompoundOperation.o) (architecture armv7):
Archive : Fabric.framework (architecture armv7s)
Fabric.framework(FABApplication.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABSettingsOnboardingManager.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABByteUtility.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABUUID.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABIcon.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(Fabric.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABNetworkOperation.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABHost.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABURLBuilder.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABCertificatePinner.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABAppIconUtility.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABMultipartMimeStreamEncoder.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABSettings.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABApplicationIdentiferModel.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABDownloadAndSaveSettingsOperation.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABCerts.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABNetworkResponseHandler.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABOnboardingOperation.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABNetworkClient.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABConstants.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(CLSdSYM.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(CLSCodeMapping.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(CLSMachOBinary.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(CLSMachOSlice.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(CLSMachO.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSessionDownloadTask.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSessionTask.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSessionDataTask.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSession.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSessionConfiguration.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSessionUploadTask.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(CLSUserDefaults.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABAsyncOperation.o) (architecture armv7s):
Fabric.framework(FABCompoundOperation.o) (architecture armv7s):
Archive : Fabric.framework (architecture arm64)
Fabric.framework(FABApplication.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABSettingsOnboardingManager.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABByteUtility.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABUUID.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABIcon.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(Fabric.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABNetworkOperation.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABHost.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABURLBuilder.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABCertificatePinner.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABAppIconUtility.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABMultipartMimeStreamEncoder.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABSettings.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABApplicationIdentiferModel.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABDownloadAndSaveSettingsOperation.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABCerts.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABNetworkResponseHandler.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABOnboardingOperation.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABNetworkClient.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABConstants.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(CLSdSYM.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(CLSCodeMapping.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(CLSMachOBinary.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(CLSMachOSlice.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(CLSMachO.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSessionDownloadTask.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSessionTask.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSessionDataTask.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSession.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSessionConfiguration.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(CLSURLSessionUploadTask.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(CLSUserDefaults.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABAsyncOperation.o) (architecture arm64):
Fabric.framework(FABCompoundOperation.o) (architecture arm64):
```

Anyone have any ideas for solving this issue?

Comment: Did you found any solution for this error ?

Comment: I would love to  know also as am stuck with a a third party dependency preventing me releasing to TestFlight and these errors are useless!